# VB.NET textbox remove last dash

Tags: vb.net, loops

How can I remove the last `-` added after the code has been entered.

All the `-` are automatically added.

Here my code :

```
Dim strKeyTextField As String = txtAntivirusCode.Text
Dim n As Integer = 5
Dim intlength As Integer = txtAntivirusCode.TextLength

While intlength > 4
    If txtAntivirusCode.Text.Length = 5 Then
        strKeyTextField = strKeyTextField.Insert(5, "-")
    End If

    Dim singleChar As Char
    singleChar = strKeyTextField.Chars(n)

    While (n + 5) < intlength
        If singleChar = "-" Then
            n = n + 6

            If n = intlength Then
                strKeyTextField = strKeyTextField.Insert(n, "-")
            End If
        End If
    End While

   intlength = intlength - 5
End While

'' Define total variable with dashes
txtAntivirusCode.Text = strKeyTextField
'sets focus at the end of the string
txtAntivirusCode.Select(txtAntivirusCode.Text.Length, 0)
```

Output is : `XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-`

What I want : `XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX`

Comment: If you haven't tried it already, perhaps a [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) with the mask set to `"&&&&&-&&&&&-&&&&&-&&&&&-&&&&&"` would suffice. It copes with deleting past the dashes automatically. (It's in the "Toolbox"->"All Windows Forms" section.)

Answer (score 2):

You could just remove the last char in the string like that:

```
txtAntivirusCode.Text = strKeyTextField.Substring(0, strKeyTextField.Length - 1)
```

or

```
txtAntivirusCode.Text = strKeyTextField.Remove(strKeyTextField.Length - 1)
```

or

```
txtAntivirusCode.Text = strKeyTextField.Trim({" "c, "-"c})
```

or

```
txtAntivirusCode.Text = strKeyTextField.TrimEnd(CChar("-"))
```

If there is a possibility of a space at the end of the string use `.Trim()` before Substring and/or Remove

Comment: It unfortunately does not work, after i type a letter is just crashes. 
error : Length cannot be less than zero

Comment: What do you mean with typing a letter? you need to remove the "-" after you did the whole loop. but before outputting the string

Comment: try this: txtAntivirusCode.Text = strKeyTextField.TrimEnd(CChar("-"))

Comment: I added 4 ways to remove the "-" Tell me if one of these helped

Comment: @G43beli You might like the [ToCharAray() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx), e.g. `.Trim(" -".ToCharArray())`, which is certainly easier to type than using lots of quotes and commas for a few chars. Or character literals, e.g. `"-"c`.

Answer (score 2):

The other way from removing the last "-" is to not add the last "-", for example:

```
Dim s = "ABCDE-FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Dim batchSize = 5
Dim nBatches = 5
Dim nChars = nBatches * batchSize

' take out any dashes
s = s.Replace("-", "")
' make sure there are not too many characters
If s.Length > nChars Then
    s = s.Substring(0, nChars)
End If

Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder

For i = 1 To s.Length
    sb.Append(s.Chars(i - 1))
    If i Mod batchSize = 0 AndAlso i <> nChars Then
        sb.Append("-")
    End If
Next

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())

Console.ReadLine()
```

Outputs:

```
ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question, what my script currently is doing is each time I write a license in the textbox and on the 5th is automatically adds an '-' but when Im finished with my license with is 25 long it automatically adds an '-' at the end again.

Comment: @UmitCanbolat 1) My code will do what you want, you just need to change some variable names. 2) Can you see somewhere in your code that you could put in a check for the length of the string, and if it is <29 then add a "-"?